# Excel - calculate backwards from cell based on changing its value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Markup calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpm3B.png)

What formula do I require in the 'client charge' cell in order for that to calculate based on the percentage I put in the 'markup' cell?

Comment: What value does the markup apply to?

Answer (score 0):

If the markup cell is calculated based on the client charge, you can't change client charge based on markup because that would be a circular reference.

Your options are to use the built in Excel Solver function, or create a new cell which calculates the recommended client charge.